# Convert Color-Indexed Image to Indexes

Tags: image, colors, libraries

I have a directory of images in png format, which use a fixed color index for their encoding.  I'm interested in producing images whose grayscale values correspond to the index itself, not the color for that index.

For example, suppose the color index has the entry index 3 -> (255, 0, 0) (red).  I want to replace every instance of (255, 0, 0) in the RGB image with the grayscale value of 3.

My first thought is to 1) hard code the reversed color index into a lookup table 2) load the image, 3) iterate over pixels, doing a replace based on the look up table.

The problem with this is hard coding the lookup table.  I can get it (via imagemagick identify), but that's tedious.  Are there any libraries that can do this for me?  I'm looking for either 1) cmd line transformations or 2) code libraries that get the color index for a pixel.

Answer (score 1):

If you open a palettised image in PHP using GD, but accidentally forget to tell GD that it is palettised, you will actually get the palette index in the blue pixel. So you could take advantage of that to create a grayscale image by creating a truecolour image the same size as your original and then writing the palette index three times, once each for the Red, Green and Blue channels. It's easier than it sounds, here is the code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php
<?php
// Read in a palettised image
$im = imagecreatefrompng("pal.png");

// Create output image same size
$out = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($im), imagesy($im));

for ($x = 0; $x < imagesx($im); $x++) {
    for ($y = 0; $y < imagesy($im); $y++) {
        $pixel = imagecolorat($im, $x, $y);
        $index = $pixel & 0xFF;
        $outCol = imagecolorallocate($out,$index,$index,$index);
        imagesetpixel($out,$x,$y,$outCol);
        // printf("[%d,%d] Palette index:%d\n",$x,$y,$index);
    }
}
imagepng($out,"result.png");
?>
```

So, if I create a 3 pixel palettised image with ImageMagick like this:

```
convert xc:red xc:lime xc:blue +append pal.png
```

and check it has palette like this

```
    identify -verbose pal.png  | more
    Image: pal.png
      Format: PNG (Portable Network Graphics)
      Mime type: image/png
      Class: PseudoClass
      Geometry: 3x1+0+0
      Units: Undefined
      Type: Palette                  <--- it has a palette
      Endianess: Undefined
      Colorspace: sRGB
      Depth: 8/1-bit
      Channel depth:
        red: 1-bit
        green: 1-bit
        blue: 1-bit
      Channel statistics:
        Pixels: 3
        Red:
          min: 0 (0)
          max: 255 (1)
          mean: 85 (0.333333)
          standard deviation: 120.208 (0.471405)
          kurtosis: -1.5
          skewness: 0.707107
          entropy: 0.918296
        Green:
          min: 0 (0)
          max: 255 (1)
          mean: 85 (0.333333)
          standard deviation: 120.208 (0.471405)
          kurtosis: -1.5
          skewness: 0.707107
          entropy: 0.918296
        Blue:
          min: 0 (0)
          max: 255 (1)
          mean: 85 (0.333333)
          standard deviation: 120.208 (0.471405)
          kurtosis: -1.5
          skewness: 0.707107
          entropy: 0.918296
      Image statistics:
        Overall:
          min: 0 (0)
          max: 255 (1)
          mean: 85 (0.333333)
          standard deviation: 120.208 (0.471405)
          kurtosis: -1.5
          skewness: 0.707107
          entropy: 0.918296
      Colors: 3
      Histogram:
             1: (  0,  0,255) #0000FF blue
             1: (  0,255,  0) #00FF00 lime
             1: (255,  0,  0) #FF0000 red
      Colormap entries: 4
      Colormap:                                       <--- here is the palette
             0: (255,  0,  0) #FF0000 red
             1: (  0,255,  0) #00FF00 lime
             2: (  0,  0,255) #0000FF blue
             3: (255,255,255) #FFFFFF white
```

Then check the `result.png` after running the PHP script, it now looks like this - i.e. greyscale and the colours match the former indices.

```
identify -verbose result.png
Image: result.png
  Format: PNG (Portable Network Graphics)
  Mime type: image/png
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 3x1+0+0
  Units: Undefined
  Type: Grayscale               <--- it is now greyscale, no palette
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    gray: 8-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 3
    Gray:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 2 (0.00784314)
      mean: 1 (0.00392157)
      standard deviation: 0.816497 (0.00320195)
      kurtosis: -1.5
      skewness: 0
      entropy: 1
  Colors: 3
  Histogram:
         1: (  0,  0,  0) #000000 gray(0)
         1: (  1,  1,  1) #010101 gray(1)
         1: (  2,  2,  2) #020202 gray(2)
```

Note that if your original image had very few colour palette entries, the output image will be dark so you will want to contrast-stretch or normalize it...